# Using box-sizing to create an inside border

Tags: html, css

I want to create an HTML table where each cell is clickable, and clicking on a cell adds a border to the single `div` within the cell.  I want that `div`'s border to exist entirely within the existing confines of the `td` that contains it, without resizing the table or its cells at all.  I can't seem to make this happen correctly.

This [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9601357/css-border-inside-div-not-on-edge) seems to address the same issue and points to some articles about the box-sizing CSS options.  I have a fiddle where I tried to implement this without success: http://jsfiddle.net/YsAGh/3/.

```
* {
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
}


<table>
  <tr>
    <td><div>1</div></td>
    <td><div>2</div></td>
    <td><div>3</div></td>
  </tr>
  ....
</table>
```

Here's what currently happens.  The border causes the containing `td` to grow to accommodate the `div`'s border.

[image: I want the red border to appear without resizing the td]

How can I add the border to the div without it affecting the containing table?

Comment: Could you simply add a border to the `.unselected` class (i.e. `.unselected { border: 2px solid yellow; }`. I'm not putting as answer since it doesn't really answer your question, just provides a hack solution.

Comment: Hmm, I'd be tempted to use jQuery to resize the cell in the click function, although this might also be considered a hack too... although @kunalbhat's answer would be a much more elegant solution, and is very easy: http://jsfiddle.net/YsAGh/4/

Comment: This won't fix the issue, but it's important that you put the unprefixed rule last e.g.`*{-webkit-box-sizing:border-box; -moz-box-sizing:border-box; box-sizing:border-box;}`. This way, the browser will try to use the correct / finished unprefixed version first and then, if not implemented, fall back to the prefixed / under development version.

Comment: Also, dare I ask: why a table?

Comment: @kunalbhat Why a table? Because this part of the project involves rendering several 24 x 16 grids, and a table seems perfect for that.  It's not for some contrived layout, at least.

Comment: I would handle it more like this - http://jsfiddle.net/devitate/YsAGh/10/.  This way your grids are built already too just by changing the var rows.

Answer (score 1):

Look at my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YsAGh/6/).

You need to provide a width/height to your cells:

```
td {
    // ...
    width:33.3%;
    height:33.3%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using an inset box-shadow?

```
.selected {
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 2px red;
}
```

Comment: Be careful, this property in [not compatible with IE8](http://caniuse.com/css-boxshadow) (and Windows XP)

Comment: Ie8 most certainly doesn't deserve compatability let alone anything fancy

Comment: Fortunately this is an in-house app and we can assume IE9+ or most recent Firefox or Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

OK, since I've seen a some support for my response in the comments, here it as an answer :)

Presize your cell by adding a yellow 'hidden' border to the `.unselected` state:

**CSS**

```
.unselected {
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 2px solid yellow; // Presize with this yellow border
}

div {
  ..
  line-height: 1; // Add line-height to regulate size (optional)
}
```

[Codepen example.](http://cdpn.io/muxIb)

Answer (score 0):

Using `table-layout` to fix the width of cells and small `padding` in `selected` to prevent increasing height.

```
table {
    table-layout: fixed;
}
.selected {
    padding: 1px;
}
```

**See** [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YsAGh/8/)