# CSS - box-sizing issue

Tags: html, css, web, border-box

I did not find any answer for my question, even if it is really simple.
I am using the CSS proprety box-sizing to do an "inside border" for a div (which is actually a `<a>...</a>`)

```
.myDiv{ 
       box-sizing: border-box; 
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
       -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       border: 2px solid #3498db;
}
```

But it seams that it is not working at all as the border is the same without border-box properties. Anyone has an answer?

Just to be sure of what I am doing. What I want is to get a `<a>` an "inside border". I obviously know the `border: ...;` property but it is making the element bigger and I don't want that. I would like to have something like `border: -2px solid #3498db`.

[EDIT] I found a solution. Description on the comments.

Comment: That's not what box-sizing does.  What on earth are you talking about?

Comment: Ok then I misunderstood what I read before. I want to do a border for a div which is inside the div.

Comment: `box-sizing: border-box` should work like that:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9601357/css-border-inside-div-not-on-edge

Comment: The problem is that my div is actually just a <a></a> and it has no fixed size. Any solution?

Comment: @SLaks - What I want to do is to add a border to a <a>. But I want it to be "inside" and not make the <a> element bigger. Do you get what I mean?

Comment: If your <a> tag is an inline element, adding a border will always increase its size and box-sizing will not help there. Also, you need to specify height for box-sizing to work. Without a height, the border still sits outside the block and affects rendering.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You made the border-box really clear for me. ;)

Comment: Hey guys.

I actually found the answer to my question.
What I wanted to do is add an inside 2px bottom border to a `<a>...</a>`.

What I did was to reduce by 2px the padding-bottom of the a and then add my border-bottom.
Here the result :

http://i.stack.imgur.com/7tjcX.png

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `box-sizing: border-box` on an inline element with no width will not make the border internal to the elements size.

Instead you can use the `:after` pseudo element to make the border over the top of the element.

**HTML**

```html
This is some <span class="textBorder">text</span> and then some more.
```

**CSS**

```css
.textBorder {
    background: #ffff99;
    position: relative;
}
.textBorder:after {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PS5dL/)**

Answer (score 1):

The easy way is to put a `<span>` inside the `<a>` and then put a border on the `<span>`. Then put the nessesary padding/margin on, either the `<a>` or the `<span>`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It will not solve my problem but it will surely help me in the future. Thanks !