# border increase moves div on hover transition

Tags: html, css

In this example, I've added an inset border transition on hover. However, when the border appears, it seems to push the div down to the right. Is there a way around this? Maybe there is a better way to get a "glow" effect around the entire div itself?

I've tried setting elements as fixed, but that didn't help solve the problem.

Any help here is appreciated. Code and JS Fiddle below:

*JS Fiddle:* http://jsfiddle.net/w3kn1tun/

**CSS:**

```
body {
    height:97.54%;
    width:98.8%;
    background-color:#0C0C0B;
}
#nw {
    background-image:url('clevelandnight.jpg');
    position:absolute;
    height:50%;
    width:49%;
    background-size:cover;
    border-radius:10px;
}
#ne {
    background-image:url('news2.jpg');
    position:absolute;
    background-size:cover;
    height:50%;
    width:49.4%;
    left:50%;
    border-radius:10px;
}
#sw {
    background-image:url('drinks1.jpg');
    position:absolute;
    background-size:cover;
    height:46.5%;
    width:49%;
    top:52.15%;
    border-radius:10px;
}
#se {
    background-image:url('clevelandday.jpg');
    position:absolute;
    background-size:cover;
    height:46.5%;
    width:49.4%;
    left:50%;
    top:52.15%;
    border-radius:10px;
}
.titletext {
    text-align:center;
    margin:0;
    font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
    font-weight:100;
    color:white;
    white-space:nowrap;
    font-size:200%;
}
.outline {
    transition:all .4s ease-out;
}
.outline:hover {
    border:4px inset white;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='stylesheet2.css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <title>CDC</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='nw' class='outline'>
      <p class='titletext'>Nightlife</p>
    </div>
    <div id='ne'>
      <p class='titletext'>News</p>
    </div>
    <div id='sw'>
      <p class='titletext'>Food & Drink</p>
    </div>
    <div id='se'>
      <p class='titletext'>Events</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That is because you are adding a border of 4px on hover..

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS Border Inside Div not on edge](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9601357/css-border-inside-div-not-on-edge)

Comment: Check this http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/w3kn1tun/2/

Comment: @Lal That's what I was looking for. Thank you. Sometimes it just takes another perspective to spot something simple.

Comment: @Lal, Ill upvote it you add it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your code was that you were adding a border when it was hovered. **[JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/w3kn1tun/2/)**

So, here I've changed your CSS as follows

```
.outline {
    transition:border .4s ease-out;
    border:4px solid #0C0C0B;
}
.outline:hover {
    border-color:white;
}
```

I made a div with a border with colour same as that of the background colour, and changed that to white only when it is hovered. **This solution wont move your div contents while hovered**

Comment: +1 for setting border first, prevents any movement when set and color change instead.

Comment: Hey..thanks @Brian.. :) Hope you could give that +1 as votes.. ;)

Comment: I voted it :) it makes sense because it doesn't change the width

Comment: @Lal ...and +0001) from me :)

Comment: you can use `transparent` as the initial color

Comment: ya..i forgot that...thanks for coming up with that.. :) @Brian

Answer (score 4):

Add `box-sizing: border-box;` to `#nw`

**JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nqsuowpm/)**

```
#nw {
    background-image:url('clevelandnight.jpg');
    position:absolute;
    height:50%;
    width:49%;
    background-size:cover;
    border-radius:10px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

**OR:** You could add `border-width: 4px;` and `border-style: solid;` to `#nw`

**JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/eu0pu20a/)**

```
#nw {
    background-image:url('clevelandnight.jpg');
    position:absolute;
    height:50%;
    width:49%;
    background-size:cover;
    border-radius:10px;
    border-width: 4px;
    border-style: solid;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works well. I guess I never used the box-sizing property enough to realize that would be the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Use `outline:` instead of `border:`

```
.outline:hover {
    outline: 4px inset white;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w3kn1tun/4/)

Comment: how do you recommend the OP maintain the `border-radius`?