# Button border on hover moves the text inside

Tags: html, css, css-animations, keyframe

I have created a border-like keyframe CSS style. When I hover the button the border-like animation should start from top-right to top-left then to bottom-left then after to bottom-right and finally to top-right again. When I hover the button the previous sequence should happen and is already created. However; when hovered, the text inside the button moves, which makes the button looks weird.

I looked at the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26077264/border-increase-moves-div-on-hover-transition), but it's not applicable in my case as I am not using border styling on hover. Instead, I am changing the background color, width, and height of the three spans, not borders.

How can I prevent this shake with the method the animation is created?

CodePen: https://codepen.io/Tes3awy/pen/ZZRpBW

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
      <a class="custom-btn" href="https://mince.34way.com/about/" title="About">
        About Us
        <span class="border-top"></span>
        <span class="border-right"></span>
        <span class="border-bottom"></span>
        <span class="border-left"></span>
      </a>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
}

.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.custom-btn {
  position: relative;
  width: 183px;
  height: 55px;
  line-height: 55px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 2px solid #77a942;
  color: #77a942;
  text-decoration: none;
}

span[class^="border-"] {
  opacity: 0;
}

.border-top {
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.border-left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -2px;
  width: 3px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.border-bottom {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -2px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.border-right {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: -2px;
  width: 3px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.custom-btn:hover .border-top {
  animation: animateTop .2s 1 alternate ease forwards;
}

.custom-btn:hover .border-left {
  animation: animateLeft .2s 1 alternate ease forwards;
  animation-delay: .2s;
}

.custom-btn:hover .border-bottom {
  animation: animateBottom .2s 1 alternate ease forwards;
  animation-delay: .4s;
}

.custom-btn:hover .border-right {
  animation: animateRight .2s 1 alternate ease forwards;
  animation-delay: .6s;
}

@keyframes animateTop {
  0% {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    background-color: #77a942;
  }
  50% {
    width: 50%;
    height: 3px;
    opacity: 1;
    background-color: #77a942;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
    height: 3px;
    opacity: 1;
    background-color: #77a942;
  }
}

@keyframes animateLeft {
  0% {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    background-color: #77a942;
  }
  50% {
    width: 3px;
    height: 50%;
    opacity: 1;
    background-color: #77a942;
  }
  100% {
    width: 3px;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
    background-color: #77a942;
  }
}

@keyframes animateBottom {
  0% {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    background-color:#77a942;
  }
  50% {
    width: 50%;
    height: 3px;
    opacity: 1;
    background-color:#77a942;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
    height: 3px;
    opacity: 1;
    background-color:#77a942;
  }
}

@keyframes animateRight {
  0% {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    background-color: #77a942;
  }
  50% {
    width: 3px;
    height: 50%;
    opacity: 1;
    background-color: #77a942;
  }
  100% {
    width: 3px;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
    background-color: #77a942;
  }
}
```

Comment: maybe its me, but I don't see any shake to the text inside

Comment: It's not doing it on mine either - I'm using Chrome.

Comment: @kukkuz have you tried the code on CodePen? If yes, please try to zoom in to 125% and see if it shakes or not?

Comment: @Tes3awy I zoomed a bit more and yes, I see a weeny-bit shake...

Comment: @kukkuz How can I avoid this weeny-bit shake?

Comment: you should probably try something else, here is an idea where you won't need a lot of code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48695388/8620333

Comment: @TemaniAfif You are welcome to answer my question

Answer (score 0):

When you translate things by 50%, they may end up in-between pixels. When you use a transition, CSS tends to change its mind on what pixel it rounds to. Try to make sure that the button you're centering text in has height/width that CSS has a definite position it can settle on when you divide it by half.