# 100% height goes a few pixels off the page?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a box 100% height of the page. But in both Chrome and IE, the following extends a few pixels off the bottom of the page so I have to scroll. Why? Why is there a scrollbar here?

```
  <!doctype html>
  <html >
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body 
        {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            height: 100%; 
        }
        div {
            border:5px solid black;
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body >
    <div >This flows a few pixels off the bottom of the page</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

It goes a few pixels off the page because you're including a 5px border. The body of the `div` is 100% the height of the page, but the `border` sits outside of that, adding 10px total height to the page alongside the 100% height. So, on a 1000px page the height of your div will be 1010px. Remove the border and it'll be exactly the right height.

```
div {
    height: 100%;
}
```

If you still want the border, but not the unwanted extra height you can use the `box-sizing: border-box` property to place it inside the boundaries of the div

```
div {
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: And if you want the border either way, add it inside the div, not on its edge, using this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9601357/

Comment: @PauloAvelar Thank you, updated to reflect your addition

Answer (score 2):

...and here is another alternative for you :

```
html,body 
{
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0
}
div
{
    border:5px solid black;
    display:block;
    height:-moz-calc(100% - 10px);
    height:-webkit-calc(100% - 10px);
    height:calc(100% - 10px);
    width:calc(100% - 10px)
}
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

You can keep your current settings WITH 5px border by declare border-box property for all major browsers:

```
div
{
    height:100%;
    box-sizing:border-box !important;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box !important;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box !important;
}
```

Since you are dealing with 100% div size it's **highly recommended** to add the **!important** so you won't get any conflict with other properties.