# Is there a way to add overlapping borders to ALL div with css?

Tags: html, css

I did a search here but I found just info about adjacent borders. Does anybody know if it is possible to add borders to all divs just to see how the current layout works.

If you just add a 1px border, it will add 2px to the width (side by side) and will - sometimes - break the current layout.

I need this just for control purposes, something to turn on/off, not for production.

thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9601357/placing-border-inside-of-div-and-not-on-its-edge

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can better use **outline** property instead of border, because

- Outlines do not take up space, because they always placed on top of
  the box of the element which may cause them to overlap other elements
  on the page.
- Unlike borders, outlines won't allow us to set each edge to a
  different width, or set different colors and styles for each edge.
- An outline is the same on all sides.
- Outlines don't have any impact on surrounding elements apart from
  overlapping.
- Unlike borders, outlines don't change the size or position of the
  element.

```css
.outline-outer,.border-outer{
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  border:solid 1px blue;
}
.border{
  height:80px;
  width:50px;
  border:solid 1px red;
  float:left;
}
.outline{
   height:80px;
  width:50px;
  outline:solid 1px red;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="outline-outer">
  <div class="outline"></div>
  <div class="outline"></div>Outlined
</div>
<br/><br/><br/>
<div class="border-outer">
  <div class="border"></div>
  <div class="border"></div>Bordered
</div>
```

[Fiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/xzett21n/2/)

Answer (score 1):

```
    * {
    border:1px solid red;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    }
```

This will add a border to all divs inside ur layout.

`*` means global.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `box-sizing` property which

Specify elements that elements should have padding and border included in the element's total width and height. so no effect on the layout

```
* {
border: 1px solid blue;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```