# How to make border bottom inside block?

Tags: css

How to make `border-bottom` inside block after hover event?

I tried this using text-shadow, but seems it is not solution

Comment: You need to show us code that you are trying otherwise we won't be able to help you..

Comment: Can you explain it a bit.. with a codepen sample or provide the code you have tried..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Placing border inside of div and not on its edge](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9601357/placing-border-inside-of-div-and-not-on-its-edge)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

An inset box shadow seems to be what you require

```css
div {
  height: 75px;
  background: #c0ffee;
}

div:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0 -5px 0 red;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

**OR**

Use a pseudo-element

```css
div {
  height: 75px;
  background: #c0ffee;
  position: relative;
}

div:hover::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```