# my entire website shakes when i click on a link and a border is displayed

Tags: css

The issue appears when i add a border through the "active" pseudoclass to my links. It seems as if the page is trying to resize itself because of those new pixels created by the border, but i don't know why it's doing it therefore i can't fix it.

```
<body>
    <header class="upper-part">
      <nav class="main-nav">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">STORE</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <h1>THE ROOMS</h1>
    </header>
</body>
```

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  background-color: rgb(222, 221, 221);
}
.upper-part {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.524);
  background-image: url(../images/bground.jpg);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-blend-mode: darken;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
}
.main-nav {
  border-bottom: solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.158) 1.5px;
}
.main-nav li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 2px;
}
.main-nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 15px;
}
.main-nav li :hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.142);
}
a:active {
  border: solid white 1px;
}
```

Comment: Side note, avoid half-pixel measurements,e.g: `1.5px`, it could produce strange rendering results as there is no such thing as half a pixel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use box-shadow to put a border within the element without creating additional pixels.

```
a:active {
  box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 1px #fff;
}
```

I got the idea from this thread:
[Placing border inside of div and not on its edge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9601357/placing-border-inside-of-div-and-not-on-its-edge)

Comment: yeah it worked. I also came up with adding a border to the link itself and set its color as transparent so there won't be new pixels, just a new color for them, and it also worked.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I work around it:

```css
.main-nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 1px;
}
a:active {
  border: solid white 1px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

of course, it will because the border before didn't exist, then when active it exists. so it's actually simple to avoid that. just add the borders to the a and make them transparent. border: `1px solid transparent;` then when hover or active, you just change border color as long as it's the same size `1px`

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  background-color: rgb(222, 221, 221);
}
.upper-part {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.524);
  background-image: url(../images/bground.jpg);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-blend-mode: darken;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
}
.main-nav {
  border-bottom: solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.158) 1.5px;
}
.main-nav li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 2px;
}
.main-nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}
.main-nav li :hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.142);
}
a:active {
  border: solid white 1px;
}
```

```html
  <body>
    <header class="upper-part">
      <nav class="main-nav">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">STORE</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <h1>THE ROOMS</h1>
    </header>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's few options..

**Set default border**

Only add to `.main-nav` a default 1px transparent border

```
.main-nav a {
    /* after all existing styles */
    border: 1px solid transparent
}
```

This way it wont "sake" as the border width is not changing dimensions

**Use outline instead**

```
.main-nav a:active {
  // instead of existing
  outline: 1px solid white
}
```

outline doesn't "take" any space

**Use shadows**

```
.main-nav a:active {
  // instead of existing
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 1px white
}
```

Same as outline